# Remove Duplicate Entries from DB w/ Unique ID that is NOT Primary Key - Keep one of course!

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, duplication

I have a CDR Table with a "unique id" column which is not a Primary Key. During an upgrade, there were a few days where instead of one entry for a caller ringing a queue, there was multiple entries for this caller. All the entries have the same unique ID.

**What I would like to do, is delete all entries with the same unique ID, but leaving one entry.** Is there a simple way to do this? All my searching turned up results on either, DB's with no unique ID, or with a Primary key. I have both a unique ID and No Primary key lol.

Thanks for your guidance!

PS: MySQL 5.5

Eg:
[image]

Comment: When you say, `unique id`, do you mean it is supposed to be unique, but it has same value repeated? If it is a `UNIQUE KEY`, no duplication is allowed. Data sample would be helpful

Comment: @JehadKeriaki Yes the row name is "unique ID", but there are duplicate Unique ID's. It is not a Primary Key, so its not MySQL's fault that it allowed multiple entries with the same Unique ID

Comment: That is one ring in the queue... so you image, that table grew a lot those 2 days! Thankfully, we can export to excel and de-duplicate, but id like to fix the data in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than, say, half the table needs to be removed, it is faster (etc) to

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
ADD PRIMARY KEY (...);   -- or UNIQUE
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM real;
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do that [DO MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE TRYING]:

1- Using ALTER IGNORE:

```
ALTER IGNORE my_tablee ADD UNIQUE (CallerID);
```

2- Create a new table, with the same structure, and preferably add the unique key in order not to fall into the same problem in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE my_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY CallerID;
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE (CallerID); --Optional
```

Comment: But I do have multiple unique entries with the same caller ID will this remove those? I'll test next week thanks u

Comment: In the provided queries, replace `CallerID` with the name of the unique id field.